# How can we integrate a simple Java Project with a Spring Project?

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, integration, autowired

I have a working Spring(MVC) project which I want to integrate with a simple java project (intended as daemon process).

I have added the Spring project to the simple Java Project in Eclipse but I am unable to invoke the Spring behavior for the service I want to use from the Spring-Hibernate project in the simple java project. All in am getting is a NullPointerException for the @Autowired entity in the Spring project. The Spring MVC project is already up and running while I am trying to run the daemon java program.

Though I am able to run the daemon process if I copy all the required service classes from the Spring project to the java project along with adding the required Spring jars (Basically making the original simple java as a Spring project now), I want to know how can Spring services be expoited by another simple java program.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state what spring version you are using. I assume it could be Spring3, but there should not be much differences in other versions ( > 2.5 ).

According to the Spring Framework Reference Manual (Chapter The IoC container) : *Several implementations of the ApplicationContext interface are supplied out-of-the-box with Spring. In standalone applications it is common to create an instance of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext or FileSystemXmlApplicationContext*

A little further in same chapter :

*Instantiating a Spring IoC container is straightforward. The location path or paths supplied to an ApplicationContext constructor are actually resource strings that allow the container to load configuration metadata from a variety of external resources such as the local file system, from the Java CLASSPATH, and so on.*

```
ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"services.xml", "daos.xml"});
```

The javadoc of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` says that this constructor (specifying context locations *Create a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, loading the definitions from the given XML file(s) and automatically refreshing the context*.

I currently use that kind of standalone initialization in tests.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Serge Ballesta.
I am using Spring 3.2.4 here. I am able to work through this with context initialization, but that means transforming my simple java program to a Spring program. I don't wan to do it as there is already a web component of my other application I want to reuse from Java application, is a Spring project.